# ModSecurity with Apache Apache/2.4.10, windows 8 configurations

Tags: mysql, apache, mod-security

I have installed Apache 2.4.10 with MySQL long time ago and using it without problems. I tried to add ModSecurity firewall to my website for security purposes. I followed all tutorials of how to configure Mod Security on Apache 2.4.* but I am still not able to run the server after the configurations. I followed this tutorial here http://mewbies.com/how_to_install_mod_security_for_apache_tutorial.htm and other tutorials like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ATQ1sqqtwQk,  but the server didn't work after following any of them. when I try to run the server it gives me the error message that apache can't start.
I tried the following solutions but nothing worked:
1. changing the port number in the configuration files.
2. Restart apache
and a lot more tricks that I don't remember, but nothing helped!
Is there a system variable I need to change or anything else that is not explicitly mentioned in the tutorials, that can help in making the server work?
thanks

Comment: Not enough info to help. Sorry to be harsh, but it's just a meandering story with no detail. Can you give the exact error message from the logs? Also check out this post: http://serverfault.com/questions/671173/mod-security-not-working-at-all/672078#672078

Comment: Here is the error message. 
10:12:12 PM  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
10:12:12 PM  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
10:12:12 PM  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
10:12:12 PM  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
10:12:12 PM  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
10:12:12 PM  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
10:12:12 PM  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums

Comment: and nothing shows up in the error log!

Comment: Which version of ModSecurity? Reduce it down as much as possible. If you load Apache but no ModSecurity configured does it work? Also try some of the suggestions here: https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=6570

Comment: Apache loads by itself but when I configure it with ModSecurity it doesn't work. I tried mod_security2-2.8.0 at first, then I tried mod_security-2.9.0 and both had the same error.

Comment: Have you tried starting without any ModSecurity config to narrow down if the module is the problem or your config?